# Comparing arrays of different sizes without any loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, compare

The question goes like this:

Given two arrays, `a` & `b` (both with positive integers).

A `special number` is a number which `a(i) == i` (the value equals to the index).

How can you check if array `b` contains a value which is a `special number` of `a`.

For example: `a = [9 9 3 9]`, `b = [3 4 5]`. Output will be `3`. If `b` or `a` are empty, output is `0`. If `b` contains several `special number`, only the smallest one will be shown.

This is what I have managed to do by far, can't progress from here..

```
a = input('Please enter the array a : ');
b = input('Please enter the array b : ');

indexedArray = 1:length(a);
c = a-indexedArray;
t = find(c==0);   
p = find(t==b);
```

does not work.

**BTW: Can only use these functions: . sort , isempty , all , any , find , sum , max , min , length. No loops or conditions! Allowed only to use an array. No matrix. Cannot use logical operators such as &, |**

Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework? Are `a` and `b` vectors, or can they be higher-dimensional arrays (matrices, etc.?).

Comment: vectors.. managed to make it work with "ismember".. but can't use this function.

Comment: (a and b are 1 dimentional arrays)

Comment: Can use only length..

Comment: Partial answer: `a(1:length(a) == a)` should return the vector containing all the "special numbers".

Comment: @Jubobs actually the `find` is unnecessary, `a(a==1:length(a))` is enough.

Comment: @David Yes, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: @David, could you explain why the a==1 make it works?

Comment: @Osh24 It's not `a==1`, it's `a==1:length(a)`. This return a vector of logical indices (`1` if `a(i)==i`, `0` otherwise). If you then apply `a` to that, you get the vector of all "special numbers".

Comment: @David ah sorry, didn't know why I had problems with understanding it. That's quite basic. Any idea about the next step? comparing a & b.

Comment: Is this homework? You shouldn't expect a full solution...

Comment: By the way, any way to overcome the issue when an empty array is inserted? (recieving an error).

Comment: Just use `isempty` (which you even have mentioned in the question) and then print: "the array is empty"

Comment: can you use `bsxfun`?

Comment: This is a really contrived homework problem. Not being able to use any of the specialized functions in the comments is like telling someone to cook a meal using only rocks and fire. Having those tools available is what makes MATLAB unique. If you can't use them, then there's no point in using MATLAB.

Comment: @rayryeng: I agree. It might teach a bit about indexing, though (see my solution), but rather than making people do puzzles, why not let them do a problem where indexing is actually useful in a real-world problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was holding off posting my solution because I [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006489/comparing-arrays-of-different-sizes-without-any-loop/27023376?noredirect=1#comment42571940_27023376) suspected that this question was a homework assignment. However, since the OP has accepted [Jonas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27023376/2541573), I might as well post mine.

## Code

A combination of `sum`, `length`, `any`, and `min` does the trick:

```matlab
function out = stupidTutor(a, b)

a        = sum(a, 1);           % if a is empty, replace it by a 1-by-0 matrix
specials = a(a == 1:length(a)); % construct the vector of special numbers
b        = sum(b, 1);           % if b is empty, replace it by a 1-by-0 matrix

% some dyadic-product shenanigans
A   = specials' * (b == b);
B   = (specials == specials)' * b;
ind = any(A == B, 1);

temp = min(b(ind));         % temp is either a scalar, a 1-by-0 matrix, or []
out  = sum(sum(temp, 2), 1); % trick to return 0 in case temp be 1-by-0 or []
```

## Tests

```
%               a           b                 result
stupidTutor([9 9 3 9]  , [3 4 5])       %       3  
stupidTutor([9 9 3 9]  , [9 8])         %       0
stupidTutor([9 9 9 9 5], [3 4 5 3])     %       5
stupidTutor([9 9 3 9 5], [3 4 5 3])     %       3
stupidTutor([9 9 3 9 5], [5 4 3 2 1])   %       3
stupidTutor([9 9 3 9]  , [])            %       0
stupidTutor([]         , [3 4 5])       %       0
stupidTutor([]         , [])            %       0
```

Comment: I love your function name - +1.

Comment: @rayryeng I drew inspiration from your comments :)

Comment: Nice, solution, uses matrices, though (i.e. 2d arrays). I assumed these were no allowed.

Comment: @Jonas There was no reference to 2D arrays in the question, so I just rolled with it. Whether they're allowed is unclear. On the other hand, isn't everything in MATLAB "2D" by default anyway?

Comment: It originally didn't say anything about matrices which is what my solution had. The OP corrected me and said they weren't allowed. He or she has changed the specifications at least three times since this post was created. That is probably contributing to my disdain of this question.... And the fact that it's completely contrived.

Comment: @rayryeng ffs... I give up on this question as well. Let it be downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: @Jubobs - Couldn't agree more my friend.

Answer (score 2):

Well, turns out there might be a way after all :). We make use of the fact that the numbers have to be strictly positive to be special numbers at all.

```
%# in case we need to handle empty inputs: replace empty input with 0 or 1, respectively.
a = sum(a(:)',1);
bIsEmpty = isempty(b);
b = sum(b(:)',1); b = max(b,1);

specialNumber = find(a==1:length(a));

maxAB = max(max(a), max(b));

%# "zeros()"
bigVectorForComparisonA = (1:maxAB)*0;
bigVectorForComparisonB = (1:maxAB)*0;

bigVectorForComparisonA(specialNumber) = 1;
bigVectorForComparisonB(b) = 1;

%# instead of &, we add. Find only the smallest match
specialNumberInB = find(bigVectorForComparisonA + bigVectorForComparisonB == 2,1,'first');

out = sum(specialNumberInB) * ~bIsEmpty; %# sum([]) = 0
```

For a slightly prettier solution that assumes up to 1 special number in `a`

```
specialNumber = min(find(a==(1:length(a)));

out = any(b==specialNumber)*sum(specialNumber);
```

Comment: +1 - This is what I had in mind essentially, but got miffed when I couldn't use `&`.  Thank you for solving this God awful problem.

Comment: The question contains the following spec: *If `b` or `a` are empty, output is `0`*. Your approach fails if `a` is empty; you get a `Matrix dimensions must agree` error.

Comment: @Jubobs: I do not think that there's a requirement for handling empty inputs. Anyway, I can fix that.

Comment: `unique()` is not something we are allowed to use. Sorry, this question is a pain in the ass. By the way, if `a` or `b` are empty, `0` is displayed.

Comment: @Jonas You have an unmatched closing parens on the second last line.

Comment: @Jubobs: the question also says: *Given two arrays, a & b (both with positive integers).* - I assume that it means that there is at least one positive integer in each. Anyway, I have added a statement to fix that.

Comment: @jubobs - it's an assignment given by my matlab tutor. Mainly to improve our knowledge with basic functions.

Comment: @Jubobs: saw that a solution would be found if `a=1,b=[]`, so I added another bit. Thanks for your testing.

Comment: @Osh24 - No offense, but your MATLAB tutor sucks.  They should be teaching you how to use MATLAB efficiently, not getting you to jump around and do something in 10 lines of code when it can be done in 2.  This is probably the most frustrating problem I have ever tried to answer and have read in my history of answering questions here on StackOverflow.  Half of it is due to you forgetting requirements and you having to constantly modify your problem.