# How to check two array list are same content in same position

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

How to check value and its position are same in 2 array list wi?.

Example:

```
//These should be not equal.
ArrayList<String> listA = {"a", "b", "c"}
ArrayList<String> listB = {"b", "c", "a"}
```

In this example element are not same position in both array list so return false..
How to check same value in same position without using `for loop`

I want to expected result this if.

```
    //These should be equal.
ArrayList<String> listA = {"a", "b", "c"}
ArrayList<String> listB = {"a", "b", "c"}
```

this type array list then return true because the value and position are same in both array..

Comment: `return listA.equals(listB)`. If you don't like `for` loop, use `while`

Comment: Check this question [Comparing arrays of different sizes without any loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006489/comparing-arrays-of-different-sizes-without-any-loop)

Comment: hehee @Qiu seems an academic question, i guess `Arrays.equals` is cheatting :D

Comment: Voting to reopen, since anwer to this question is going to be significantly different from answers to the duped question, as Matlab and java are completely different languages.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
return listA.equals(listB);
```

> Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both
>   lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in
>   the two lists are equal.