# Search same colors (RGB) in same position (i, j) from different arrays (3 array) and lock it

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist

I made a simple learning program to create 3 Array, put `JPanel` into it, and then give random color for each (each Array have its own "randomizer" `JtoggleButton`)

For learning continuation, I am thinking of creating 1 more button to search the same colors in same position from that Arrays like array1 [0][0] (r, g, b) = array2 [0][0] (r, g, b), and then **lock it** (so the loop can't revalidate its color).

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to lock only a position of array like array [0][9]?
2. I think I should make the randomizing loops synchronize first, is
   that methodically right?
3. If it is possible, from where should I start to build it?
4. It is not a question but, please give me instigation if I make unnecessary "// copy method" except for the JToggleButtons.

P.S. the only question like this is [How to check two array list are same content in same position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070121/how-to-check-two-array-list-are-same-content-in-same-position), which is maybe the next step for the method, others are in different language and I don't think it has a same issue.

The code:

**Main:**

```
public class Main {

    private static void createMainFrame() {
        new Window().initMainFrame();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("Convert2Lambda")
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createMainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Window:**

```
public class Window {

    public void initMainFrame() {
        Container container = mainFrame.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(null);
    }

    private static void createBlocks1() {
        new Blocks().initBlocks1();
    }
    // createBlocks2
    // createBlocks3

    public static JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("learning 43");
    public static JPanel viewerBoard1 = new JPanel();
    // viewerBoard2
    // viewerBoard3

    public static JToggleButton randomize1 = new JToggleButton("RANDOMIZER");
    // randomize2
    // randomize3

    @SuppressWarnings("Convert2Lambda")
    public Window() {
        initMainFrame();
        mainFrame.setSize(676,357);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        mainFrame.add(viewerBoard1);
        viewerBoard1.setBounds(15, 15, 200, 200);
        viewerBoard1.setBackground(new Color(222, 222, 222));
        viewerBoard1.setVisible(true);
        // viewerBoard2
        // viewerBoard3

        JPanel viewerPanel1 = new JPanel();
        mainFrame.add(viewerPanel1);
        viewerPanel1.setBounds(10, 10, 210, 210);
        viewerPanel1.setBackground(new Color(111, 111, 111));
        viewerPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        viewerPanel1.setVisible(true);
        // viewerpanel2
        // viewerpanel3

        mainFrame.add(randomize1);
        randomize1.setFocusPainted(false);
        randomize1.setRolloverEnabled(true);
        randomize1.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        randomize1.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 16));
        randomize1.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        randomize1.setBounds(10, 230, 210, 90);
        randomize1.setVisible(true);
        randomize1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent randomEvent) {
                if (randomEvent.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    System.out.println("Randomize Button 1 selected: " + randomize1.isSelected());
                    System.out.println("randomizing panel 1...");
                    while (randomize1.isSelected()) {
                        createBlocks1();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (randomEvent.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
                    System.out.println("Randomize Button 1 deselcted!");
                    System.out.println("eraseing panel 1...");
                    viewerBoard1.removeAll();
                    viewerBoard1.revalidate();
                    viewerBoard1.repaint();
                }
            }
        });
        // randomize2
        // randomize3
    }
}
```

**Blocks:**

```
public class Blocks {

    public void initBlocks1() {
        BlockThread1 thread1 = new BlockThread1();
        thread1.start();
    }
    // initBlocks2
    // initBlocks3

    Container container = Window.viewerBoard1;
    JPanel [][] blocksArray1 = new JPanel[4][4];
    JPanel colsPanel;
    JPanel rowsPanel;
    Random random1 = new Random();
    private Color RColor1() {
        return new Color(random1.nextInt(255), random1.nextInt(255), random1.nextInt(255)/*, random.nextInt(255)*/);
    }
    class BlockThread1 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            container.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
            do {
                try {
                    for (int cols1 = 0; cols1 < blocksArray1.length; cols1++) {
                        colsPanel = new JPanel();
                        colsPanel.setBackground(RColor1());
                        Window.viewerBoard1.revalidate();
                        Window.viewerBoard1.add(colsPanel);

                        for (int rows1 = 1; rows1 < blocksArray1[cols1].length; rows1++) {
                            rowsPanel = new JPanel();
                            rowsPanel.setBackground(RColor1());
                            Window.viewerBoard1.revalidate();
                            Window.viewerBoard1.add(rowsPanel);
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    Window.viewerBoard1.removeAll();
                    Window.viewerBoard1.revalidate();
                    Window.viewerBoard1.repaint();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } while (Window.randomize1.isSelected());
        }
    }
    // blocksArray2
    // blocksArray3
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a lock. Can't you just store the points you've already compared in a Set, then just do an if check when you compare any pair of points to see if either is in that Set?

Comment: @cricket_007 i don't know the term, what i mean is when i click the "matcher" button it will lock the color of  [0][0] on first array, and search the color of [0][0] on second array, and then on the third array.

Comment: Wait............... am I answering my third question?

Comment: Set, HashSet. Those are Java classes that don't allow duplicates and have a constant time `contains` method. If you store the coordinates in this data structure, you can quickly see if you've compared two pairs of coordinates. If you have, then don't reassign their colors, making them "locked"

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you, i will learn how to work with `HashSet`.